# Mailgun can't route for internationalized domain name

Tags: email, internationalization, mailgun

--Edit-- before you read the text wall.

Mailgun responded via their support page: "IDNs are not supported with SMTP Credentials, Mailing Lists, or Routes."

I responded with a request that they clarify this in their users manual. It would have saved me hours of debugging and the cost of registering a test domain for use with the bug report.

---Original post follows

I've been trying to use mailgun to route from an international address to gmail and icloud. I've done this with normal all ascii domains. The issue seems to be that domains must be registered in punycode while routes must be submitted using the UTF8 version of the IDN. Any work arounds?

To test, consider the domain (actually registered and active on mailgun) 全日.com which has the punycode representation xn--15q621c.com.

Register domains at https://app.mailgun.com/app/domains

- Register domain xn--15q621c.com - works
- register domain 全日.com - fail: "domain name must be valid URL"

Add Routes at https://app.mailgun.com/app/routes

- add route test1@xn--15q621c.com -> elsewhere - route added successfully
- add route test2@全日.com -> same elsewhere   - route added successfully

Verify routes using test tool on same page

- enter test1@xn--15q621c.com - mailgun reports "no routes match"
- enter test2@全日.com - mailgun returns the correct route.

Attempt Sending Email

- to test1@xn--15q621c.com - mailgun returns "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied"
- to test2@全日.com - mailgun returns "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied"

Someone may suggest creating an SMTP credential - it doesn't work. It can only be done via the domain screen, so can't try for UTF version. Attempting to create smtp credential for "test1@xn--15q621c.com" - fails "Internal system error".

Comment: Mailgun responded via their support page: "IDNs are not supported with SMTP Credentials, Mailing Lists, or Routes."

Therefore, the question morphs into a request for info on who does provide such support.

Comment: It's amazin how there's no info on this anywhere. Don't really know what to do with my IDN domain now.

Comment: I'm looking into using amazon's mail service combined with amazon lambda to act as my SMTP server. Others have done it and it evaporates the need for a service like mailgun. That leaves the problem with gmail rejecting many IDNs. For that, I'm looking at setting up an additional domain name and dynamically rewriting the address so that the non-IDN version is seen only by the people using google's smtp engines.

It's all on hold due to my day job, but someday...